# WAS vs HAVE BEEN vs HAD BEEN

Tags: grammar

I want to explain about my duties in my previous job that I left 3 months ago. Which verb tense would be better to use? I should note that these duties were being done every day so I think past progressive tense should be fine.

> Everyday once I was arriving I was opening the program and printing orders list.
>
> Everyday once I was arriving I have been opening the program and printing orders list.
>
> Everyday once I was arriving I had been opening the program and printing orders list.

Comment: Could you please add more detail to your question to explain why you find this confusing, and what research you have done?  Otherwise we will have to close this as *proofreading*.

Comment: Please note that I am looking for the best verb tense to answer questions about my previous job. I need to know how can I choose a verb tense for a continues work in the past that is more common in speaking. Thanks

Comment: Sarmen, why do you think you should use the *continuous* tense?  In English, we use the simple present/past tense for *routine* actions.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I didn’t know this rule works for past tense too.

Comment: Samen could you please edit your question to add more detail?  Explain why you think the continuous tense is correct here?  I didn't say it's wrong, but I'm not sure what you are trying to say.  Also are these **printing orders**, or did you **print** the orders?

Comment: I did. Please check!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of past progressive ("I was arriving") is unnecessarily complicated.

Also, changing tenses mid-sentence can lead to confusion and ambiguity.

Since you are talking about actions that happened in the past, it's best to use **past tense** in both cases.

> Every day when I ***arrived***, I ***opened*** the program and printing orders list.

Comment: I've downvoted this for three reasons.  First, you fail to address the various other errors in Sarmen's sample sentences.  If you're going to help, help completely.  Second, *proofreading* questions should be closed, not answered.  It's better to ask for more detail to clarify what exactly is confusing, what research has been done, etc.  Third, you fail to explain your answer, so it's difficult to apply this advice to anything but this specific case.  In the future, please keep these in mind.

Comment: @Andrew The question specifically asked "what verb tense do I use".  I would like some help here,  Can you help me completely by editing my answer to help show me what would be more acceptable?

Comment: Well, you can explain **why** Sarmen should use the past tense here instead of either of the perfect tenses, and give some related examples.  Also I would address the word choice in the sentence, for example the ambiguity of "printing orders list" -- did he open the  *printing* orders list or did he *print* the order lists?   You can add suggestions how a native speaker would likely express this series of actions.

Comment: But as I said, I wouldn't answer the question at all, because as written he's asking us to *proofread*.  We don't do that, as a rule.

Comment: @nmath if I remove Every day from begging of the sentence it would not sound good

Comment: The suggestion in my answer did not remove "every day".  Past progressive is your use of "I was arriving" instead of "I arrived".  You can say "every day when I arrived..."

Answer (score 2):

In English, we use the simple tense to talk about *routine*.

> At my old job I **made** sales calls every day.

We use the continuous tense to talk about *simultaneity* -- things happening at the same time as other things.

> One day at my old job I **was making** sales calls when I heard the building was on fire.

We use the perfect tense to relate one event to another event.

> One day at my old job I **had made** several sales calls when I heard the building was on fire.

Past job responsibilities are *routine* actions, so it's better to use the past tense.

> At my old job, every day, after I **arrived** ...

However "I was opening the program and printing orders list" does not make sense.  I don't know if you were *opening* something called a "printing orders list" or you were *printing* an "orders list".  Either way, use the past tense for the verb.

> I **opened** the program and **printed** the orders list.
>
> I **opened** the program and the printing orders list.